# Blob storage folders bckups

Tags: azure-synapse

- we have a lot of pipelines in the synapse workspace.
- using serverless sqlpool which is set to online
- dedicated sql pool is paused as we do not use it to hold data...
- using DevOps Repository
- the support team will be making some clean-up in the environment. i.e. Running an old terraform to re-create the environment, etc.
  How is it possible to make sure that

Question:
I understand in our DevOps Repository everything seems to be backed-up except the blob storage folders...
How can we make sure that if in-case something gets lost/ or goes wrong during the workspace clean-up, we will be able to get everything back...?

Thank you

Comment: If my answer is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

ADLS Gen2 has its own tools for ensuring that DR event won’t affect you. One of the most powerful tools there is replication including Geo-Replicated Storage option.

Data Lake Storage Gen2 already handles 3x replication under the hood to guard against localized hardware failures. Additionally, other replication options, such as ZRS or GZRS, improve HA, while GRS & RA-GRS improve DR. When building a plan for HA, in the event of a service interruption the workload needs access to the latest data as quickly as possible by switching over to a separately replicated instance locally or in a new region.

In a DR strategy, to prepare for the unlikely event of a catastrophic failure of a region, it is also important to have data replicated to a different region using GRS or RA-GRS replication. You must also consider your requirements for edge cases such as data corruption where you may want to create periodic snapshots to fall back to. Depending on the importance and size of the data, consider rolling delta snapshots of 1-, 6-, and 24-hour periods, according to risk tolerances.

For data resiliency with Data Lake Storage Gen2, it is recommended to geo-replicate your data via GRS or RA-GRS that satisfies your HA/DR requirements. Additionally, you should consider ways for the application using Data Lake Storage Gen2 to automatically fail over to the secondary region through monitoring triggers or length of failed attempts, or at least send a notification to admins for manual intervention. Keep in mind that there is tradeoff of failing over versus waiting for a service to come back online.

For more details refer to [Best practices for using Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-best-practices).

And also here a great article which talks about : [Azure Synapse Disaster Recovery Architecture](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/some-notes-azure-synapse-disaster-recovery-andrei-zaichikov/?trk=read_related_article-card_title).